# Hive insert vs Hive Load: What are the trade offs?

Tags: hive, hdfs, hiveql, apache-nifi

I'm learning Hadoop/Big data technologies. I would like to ingest data in bulk into hive. I started working with a simple CSV file and when I tried to use `INSERT` command to load each record by record, one record insertion itself took around 1 minute. When I put the file into HDFS and then used the `LOAD` command, it was instantaneous since it just copies the file into hive's warehouse. I just want to know what are the trade offs that one have to face when they opt in towards `LOAD` instead of `INSERT`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Load**- Hive does not do any transformation while loading data into tables. Load operations are currently pure copy/move operations that move datafiles into locations corresponding to Hive tables.

**Insert**-Query Results can be inserted into tables by using the insert clause and which in turn runs the map reduce jobs.So it takes some time to execute.

In case if you want to optimize/tune the insert statements.Below are some techniques:

1.Setting the execution Engine in hive-site.xml to Tez(if its already installed)

```
 set hive.execution.engine=tez;
```

2.USE ORCFILE

```
CREATE TABLE A_ORC (

customerID int, name string, age int, address string

) STORED AS ORC tblproperties (“orc.compress" = “SNAPPY”);

INSERT INTO TABLE A_ORC SELECT * FROM A;
```

3. Concurrent job runs in hive can save the overall job running time .To achieve that hive-default.xml,below config needs to be changed:

```
set hive.exec.parallel=true;
set hive.exec.parallel.thread.number=<your value>;
```

For more info,you can visit http://hortonworks.com/blog/5-ways-make-hive-queries-run-faster/
Hope this helps.

Comment: Agreed.  One tradeoff where you might be "stuck" using INSERT vs LOAD is if the user does not have permissions to put files on HDFS but has a Hive user/pass. If HiveQL is your only option then you'd need INSERT instead.